# Give the missing rules for the connective $\vee$. Also give rules for $\rightarrow$ (implication)

Tags: logic

Consider the connetives $\neg$, $\wedge$ and $\vee$. Formulated using set-theoretic machinery, the rules for these, except $\vee$, have the form:

$$\left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \neg \neg \phi \right\},...,B_i \right\} \ \ \ \ \leadsto \ \ \ \ \left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \phi \right\},..,B_i \right\}$$

$$\left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \phi \wedge \psi \right\},...,B_i \right\} \ \ \ \ \leadsto \ \ \ \ \left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \phi, \psi \right\},...,B_i \right\}$$

$$\left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{  \neg (\phi \wedge \psi) \right\},...,B_i \right\} \ \ \ \ \leadsto \ \ \ \ \left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \neg\phi \right\}, B \cup \left\{ \neg \psi \right\},...,B_i \right\}$$

Give the missing rules for the connective $\vee$. Also give rules for $\rightarrow$ (implication)

So I tried to give the rules for $\vee$ and I got:

$$\left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \phi \vee \psi \right\},...,B_i \right\} \ \ \ \ \leadsto \ \ \ \ \left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \phi \right\}, B \cup \left\{ \psi \right\},...,B_i \right\}$$

$$\left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \neg(\phi \vee \psi) \right\},...,B_i \right\} \ \ \ \ \leadsto \ \ \ \ \left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \neg \phi, \neg \psi \right\},...,B_i \right\}$$

Am I correct? Can someone help?

Comment: The rules for $\lor$ are correct; they are the "dual" of those for $\land$.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for $\to$ are :

> $\{ B_1,...,B∪ \{ \phi \to \psi \} ,...,B_i \} ⇝ \{ B_1,...,B∪ \{ \lnot \phi \} ,B∪ \{ \psi \} ,...,B_i \}$

and

> $\{ B_1,...,B∪ \{ ¬(\phi \to \psi) \} ,...,B_i \} ⇝ \{ B_1,...,B∪ \{ \phi, \lnot \psi \} ,...,B_i \}$

Comment: So it is actually logic equivalences we are working with

Comment: @AlimTeacher - yes; we can read the last rule "backward" and it says that : if $\phi$ and $\lnot \psi$ are true, then $\lnot (\phi \to \psi)$ is true. Basically, it is the *tautology* : $(\phi \land \lnot \psi) \equiv \lnot (\phi \to \psi)$.